# Porting System.Configuration to .NET Core via POCOs?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We've got a `.NET Framework .dll` that we're porting to `.NET Core`. Currently we're inheriting from `ConfigurationElement` and `ConfigurationSection` from `System.Configuration` to create custom configuration sections in the `app.config` (or it's .NET Core equivalent)

Questions:

1. It appears the .NET Core way is `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. Is that correct? Because it lives on `ASP.NET Core`'s [github project](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration) instead of `.NET Core`'s [github project](https://github.com/dotnet). We have no ASP parts.
2. If so, any `.NET Core` examples on creating and loading custom configuration sections not relying on `startup.cs` ? Ideally we'd like to read from a text source (XML or JSON) directly into a POCO object graph for strongly typed benefits.
3. With .NET Core 2.0, will there be any support for the traditional `ConfigurationElement` and `ConfigurationSection` negating the need for any such porting efforts to begin with ? Reason I ask is the [.NET Core 2.0 Roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md#primary-scenarios-for-net-core-20) says

   > .NET Core gain over 5,000 APIs from .NET Framework as part of this work making it a broader platform.

Comment: What do you mean by `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` lives in ASP.NET Core? You can use it in any project. Even in full framework.

Comment: Even though it lives there it has no dependencies on anything from ASP.NET, check NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/.

Comment: I don't see a reason to reinvent a wheel.  `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` does very good job. And also supports strongly typed config objects.

Comment: Related: Configuration samples in ASP.Net Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the dust settling down from .NET Standard 2.0 release **it is** possible to use your usual `System.Configuration` even in .NET Core 2.0 on Linux!

Here is a test example:

1. Created a .NET Standard 2.0 Library (say `MyLib.dll`)
2. Added the NuGet package `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` v4.4.0. This is needed since this package isn't covered by the meta-package `NetStandard.Library` v2.0.0
3. All your C# classes derived from `ConfigurationSection` or `ConfigurationElement` go into `MyLib.dll`. For example `MyClass.cs` derives from `ConfigurationSection` and `MyAccount.cs` derives from `ConfigurationElement`. Implementation details are outof scope here but [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20custom%20configuration%20section%20tutorial)
4. Create a .NET Core 2.0 app (e.g. a console app, `MyApp.dll`). .NET Core apps end with `.dll` rather than `.exe` in Framework.
5. Create an `app.config` in `MyApp` with your custom configuration sections. This should obviously match your class designs in #3 above. For example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="myCustomConfig" type="MyNamespace.MyClass, MyLib" />
      </configSections>
      <myCustomConfig>
        <myAccount id="007" />
      </myCustomConfig>
    </configuration>
```

That's it - you'll find that the app.config is parsed properly within `MyApp` and your existing code within `MyLib` works just fine. Don't forget to run `dotnet restore` if you switch platforms from Windows (dev) to Linux (test).

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of `app.config` and `System.Configuration` support in `.NET Core`. Probably, no, but that's just a guess. You can setup configuration for `.NET Core` application in `Main` method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var poco = new Poco();
        configuration.Bind(poco);

        Console.WriteLine(poco);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Poco
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public Sort Sort { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Enabled={Enabled}, SortOrder={Sort.Order}";
    }
}

class Sort
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

`appsettings.json` is following:

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "sort": {
    "order": 2
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Enabled=True, SortOrder=2
```

You need to reference [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/) packages.

No dependency on `ASP.NET Core`.

`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` is quite extensible, it can use different settings providers like environment variables, command line arguments, etc. So it is possible to implement custom provider for `ConfigurationSection`-like configuration if needed.

Based on [this comment](http://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/254#issuecomment-289072521) they are not going to bring System.Configuration to NetStandard 2.0.

Comment: Thanks - seems like the right direction. Could you demo a sample `appsettings.json` that's read into `SamplePocoGraph`? It's trivial with just parsing JSON (e.g. JSON.net) but looking to do it the '.NET Core' way...

Comment: Sure, it is also trivial with .NET Core. Will post it in a while.

Comment: Could you also comment on question #3? .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: I haven't heard about such plans, I think it possible to search in their repo, I will try to have a look.

Comment: Based on this comment https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/254#issuecomment-289072521 they are not going to bring System.Configuration to NetStandard 2.0.

Comment: How about then https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager ? It looks like corefx 2.0 will contain System.Configuration. Even if it's not part of netstandard2.

Comment: @Shrike, looks like you are right. Don't know why I was not able to find it - looks like it is there for about four month by now. Will you post new answer?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov yeah, I'll post. probably you (as me) looked at netstandard2 api which misses these types...

Answer (score 2):

Besides described way of migration to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` (which totally makes sense) as it should (at least I hope) be possible to use the same types from `System.Configuration` on .NET Core 2.

Here's `System.Configuration` types in corefx: 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

I can't tell you that they are fully compatible with the ones from full .NET. But at least it's something that takes us a hope )

So it looks like .NET Core 2 will have that old `System.Configuration` stuff but not `netstandard2`. Probably it's because MS doesn't want to share these types among other platforms (Xamarin).